# How to Put a static UIButton Overlaying a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

Basically, I wanna create a static UIButton on top whether or not the table view is scrolled. However, I tried to add the UIButton as the subview of the UIView and make it on the top by using "bringSubviewToFront" method. However, the UIButton still moves when I scroll the UITableView. Therefore, how can I make a static UIButton overlaying the UITableView?

Here is my code:

```
#import "DiscoverTimelineTableViewController.h"

@interface DiscoverTimelineTableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView* myview;

@end

@implementation DiscoverTimelineTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self displayMakePlanButton];

    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.layer.zPosition);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.tableView.layer.zPosition);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100.0f;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Sleepy";

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Add the make plan button
- (void) displayMakePlanButton
{
    CGFloat buttonWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat buttonHeight = 104.0f;

    CGFloat navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat statBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;

    UIButton *makePlanButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [makePlanButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - buttonHeight - navBarHeight - statBarHeight, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];

    [makePlanButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.286 green:0.678 blue:0.231 alpha:1]];
    [makePlanButton setTitle:@"MAKE PLAN" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.view addSubview:makePlanButton];
    //makePlanButton.layer.zPosition = 1;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:makePlanButton];
    NSLog(@"%f", makePlanButton.layer.zPosition);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a table view controller, so self.view is the table view. A table view is a scroll view, so the view scrolls along with everything else.

You should use a regular view controller with a table as a subview instead.

Alternatively, you could try resetting the view's frame in the `scrollViewDidScroll:` scroll view delegate method, but I think the view would still jitter a bit.

Finally, you could add the button directly to the `UIWindow`, but that's likely to bring up a whole host of other problems with rotations, animations, and transitions.